# JavaScript: Create new arrays dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, geometry, algebra

Working Code: http://jsfiddle.net/sXbRK/

I have various line segments and each has its own ID. I know which ones cross each other.

Now, I need to push the ID of those overlapping line segments into new arrays.

I don't care for the line segments that don't cross each other.

How do I do push the line segment IDs that cross each other into their own array?

```
// New arrays of overlapping IDs
e.g. Array A = [1,2,3];
     Array B = [7,8,12];
     Array C = [14,15];
```

Here's what I have so far and don't forget to check the work-in-progress code on jsFiddle:

```
function cross( ls )
{
    var len = ls.length;

    for(var a=0; a < len - 1; a++)
    {
        for(var b=a+1; b < len; b++)
        {
            var A = ls[a],
                B = ls[b],
                combine = [],
                overlappers = [];

            if
            (
                (A.start <= B.start && (A.start + A.end) >= B.start)
                ||
                (A.start <= A.start && (B.start + B.end) >= A.start)
            )
            {
                // Add overlapping elements to arrays
                overlappers.push(A.id,B.id);

                // Create arrays for line segments that overlap each other
                combine[a] = new Array(overlappers);
                document.write('Array' + [a] + ' ==> ' + combine[a] + '<br />');
            }
        }
    }
}


// Test data
var lineSegments = [
    {id:'1',  start:0,    end:50},
    {id:'2',  start:0,    end:50},
    {id:'3',  start:0,    end:50},
    {id:'4',  start:100,  end:50},
    {id:'5',  start:200,  end:50},
    {id:'6',  start:300,  end:50},
    {id:'7',  start:900,  end:50},
    {id:'8',  start:900,  end:50},
    {id:'9',  start:600,  end:50},
    {id:'10', start:700,  end:50},
    {id:'11', start:800,  end:50},
    {id:'12', start:900,  end:50},
    {id:'13', start:1000,  end:50},
    {id:'14', start:1100,  end:50},
    {id:'15', start:1100,  end:50}
];

// Execute function
cross(lineSegments);
```

Please help with some ideas. Thank you!

Comment: I am not shure what your question is here. Do you need help determine which lines cross, or do you need help pushing things into arrays? What do you want to be in the array?

Comment: I want to push the ID of the overlapping line segments into a brand new array. The new array contains only the IDs of those line-segments that overlap each other

Comment: `if(/* line segments overlap*/)
 {
     // Create new arrays, add overlappers
     combine[a] = new Array(overlappers);
 }
`

...something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var lineSegments = [
    {id:'1',  start:0,    end:50},
    {id:'2',  start:0,    end:50},
    {id:'3',  start:0,    end:50},
    {id:'4',  start:100,  end:50},
    {id:'5',  start:200,  end:50},
    {id:'6',  start:300,  end:50},
    {id:'7',  start:900,  end:50},
    {id:'8',  start:900,  end:50},
    {id:'9',  start:600,  end:50},
    {id:'10', start:700,  end:50},
    {id:'11', start:800,  end:50},
    {id:'12', start:900,  end:50},
    {id:'13', start:1000,  end:50},
    {id:'14', start:1100,  end:50},
    {id:'15', start:1100,  end:50}
];


function fixSense(line) {
   if (line.start > line.end) {
     var t = line.start;
     line.start = line.end;
     line.end = t;
   }
   return line;
}

function getCrossingLines(lines) {
  var a, b;
  var overlappers = [], combined = [];

  // for each line
  for (var i=0, iLen=lines.length - 1; i<iLen; i++) {
    a = fixSense(lines[i]);

    // for every other line
    for (var j=i+1, jLen=lines.length; j<jLen; j++) {
      b = fixSense(lines[j]);

      if (  (a.start <= b.start && a.end >= b.end) ||
            (a.start <= b.start && a.end >= b.end) ||
            (a.start <= b.end && a.end >= b.end) ) {
        overlappers.push(a.id, b.id);
        combined.push([a.id, b.id]);
      }
    }
  }

  console.log('combined: ' + combined);

}

getCrossingLines(lineSegments);
```

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sXbRK/2/
??
That spits out everything on one line. Or did I copy something incorrectly?

Comment: oh I see, all of the overlappers are combined but not in their own array. Ok cool, it's a step closer! sweet. Thanks.

Comment: It creates two arrays, one with just the list of ids, the other with each pair in an array. Alerting the *combined* array just shows the whole thing as comma separated values, but it's actually an array of 2 member arrays.

Comment: @JsusSlav Does "it's a step closer!" meen we are still not where you want to be? If that is so you could give us an example of how your final array should look like (e.g. in JSON format: `combined : [idA, idB, idC, idE]` or `combined : [[idA, idB], [idE, idC]]` or `combined : [{idA, idF}, {idB, idC}]` something like that).

Comment: I did at the very top of the post:
`// New arrays of overlapping IDs
e.g. Array A = [1,2,3];
     Array B = [7,8,12];
     Array C = [14,15];
`

Comment: Taking @RobG's code, I would need the following set of arrays instead of one long string:
`combinedA = [1,2,1,3,2,3];
combinedB = [7,8,7,9,7,10,7,11,7,12];
combinedC = [8,9,8,10,8,11,8,12];
combinedD = [14,15];`

Comment: Work's well enough for now. Thanks!